# Hasura object permission based authorization

Tags: hasura, hasura-jwt

I am trying to set a "Row Select" permissions on Hasura. I have a (simplified for brevity) Data Model like below

User

```
id: UserID
```

App

```
id: AppID
```

App Permissions

```
user_id: User ID
app_id: App ID
permissions: [ ENUM: Admin, View, Owner ]
```

Feed

```
app_id: AppID
feed_data: Some Feed Data
```

Now, I wish to query all Feed for an authenticated user. The query can be of the form

- GET all apps, for which the authenticated user has view permissions

```
query MyQuery {
  feed(limit: 10) {
    app_id
    feed_data
  }
}
```

- GET apps with `app_id` in the query filter for which the authenticated user has view permissions

```
query MyQuery {
  feed(limit: 10, where: {app_id: {_in: [1, 2]}}) {
    app_id
    feed_data
  }
}
```

Since `feed` table does not have `user_id` information directly in it, I can not use `X-Hasura-User-Id` attribute directly against `feed` table. I also tried to use `_exists` relation against the `app_permission` table, but I am unable to put `app_id` filter in the permission clause.

```
{
  "_exists": {
    "_where": {
      "user_id": {
        "_eq": "X-Hasura-User-Id"
      }
    },
    "_table": {
      "schema": "public",
      "name": "app_permission"
    }
  }
}
```

I am not really sure how to proceed with such data modelling with Hasura. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you dont have a direct relationship, I think you can query via appPermissions Table instead of directly querying feeds table.

When you create a `feeds` table with appId as foreign key relationship, Hasura lets you track this relationship as shown below[image]
This way you can make nested graphQL queries to appPerms table as shown below

```
query GetUserFeeds {
  test_appPerms {
    id
    userId
    feeds(limit: 10) {
      app_id
      id
      feed_data
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @sooraj for answering my question. However, If I need to access some more nested relation, will I have to configure permission for each table?

Example - For this example, for role user, if we have feed -> website relation, and I want attributes of website in the QL, will I have to configure permission on both feed and website? Also, to be able to configure permission, I will have to create an object relation from feed, website to app_permission?

Answer (score 1):

Another thing I'd like to suggest is that you could try is by using a session variable like `x-hasura-app-id` along side a `x-hasura-role` and build your permissions around that.

https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/auth/authorization/roles-variables.html

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. However, I can not pass the app IDs in the JWT claim. The user may get additional permissions to view other apps and an app's permission can be revoked asynchronously. If I do that, I will have to verify the JWT token each time with my Auth server. Not sure if thats a very good idea.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear before but these headers would be a part of the request headers an not necessarily the claims map.